# set default image to ImageField for existing objects in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which has an `ImageField`.

```
class A(model.Model):
    blah = CharField(max_length=10)
    profile = ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to set a default image for existing data, so I tried saving the file in shell like the following:

```
>>> myapp.models import A
>>> from django.core.files import File
>>> for a in A.objects.all():
>>>    a.profile.save('default.jpg', File(open('/Users/myusername/Pictures/default.jpg', 'rb')))
```

I was quite happy, until I found out that in `myprojectroot/media/uploads/` there are as many **defaultblablah.jpg** files as the number of `A` objects.

I'd like to know if there's any way to set the same image file with all objects as you do with `update()` method.

Could someone shed some lights on it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can store a file `default.jpg` in the `uploads/` directory, and then update the objects with:

```
A.objects.filter(profile=None).update(profile='uploads/default.jpg')
```

I would also advise to make the field non-nullable, and use as default an value:

```
class A(model.Model):
    blah = CharField(max_length=10)
    profile = ImageField(
        upload_to='uploads/',
        default='uploads/default.jpg',
        blank=True
    )
```

Behind the curtains an `ImageField` is a `varchar` field in the database, that stores a path to the image you use. The Django `ImageField` has extra logic such that it presents it as a [**`FieldFile`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) with some logic, but it is stored in the database as a string.

The reason why it will generate multiple images, is because you can later decide to *edit* one of the images. If that is the case, all of the other images would see these edits. So if the filename "clashes", it will make copies to prevent this. If you however make use of a default image, the idea is to not modify that image. Therefore it might also be a good idea to mark the file as readonly.

Comment: How do you mark the file as readonly? Can you please give an example